# Visual Studio deleting source code when running Web Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am upgrading a Web project from Windows XP / Visual Studio 2010 to Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013. When I do this I get a migration report showing two warnings and 15 other messages, none of which appear to be of any consequence. I then adjust the target framework for the web project to 4.5.1 and run the project.

This displays the web page as I expect, but any interaction with it (selecting a new item on a pull-down, for instance) results in the error:-

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> The page you are looking for
>   cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being
>   used.

Attempting to discover the reason for this, I find all the source code (.aspx files, .cs files, .config files and .css files) are all missing. Fortunately I can recover them from the backups that the migration process made, but this is still rather alarming. Can anyone tell me how to prevent this? What project setting might be responsible?

**Edit** I have tried copying the code back into the project directory after displaying the web page for the first time. Selecting a new item on the pull-down then works, but deletes the source code again. So the HTTP error appears to be a consequence of the page being actually missing during the post-back.

Comment: could you post any link that you are accessing ?..just to see the link format

Comment: This VS 2013 is kind of hell.Too many issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program when it runs uses old scratch files; when it starts up it deletes them; it determines these by deleting all files of the form:-

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "*.*";
```

which at one time deleted all the files intended. On the new Windows 8 machine, the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` resolves to the null string, with the inevitable consequences...

Please excuse me while I curl up with embarrassment.

Answer (score 1):

> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) is being used.

**Cause 1**

This problem occurs because the client makes an HTTP request by using an HTTP method that does not comply with the HTTP specifications.

**Resolution :**

Make sure that the client sends a request that contains a valid HTTP method. To do this, follow these steps:
Click Start, type Notepad in the Start Search box, right-click Notepad, and then click Run as administrator.

Note If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or provide confirmation.
On the File menu, click Open. In the File name box, type `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config`, and then click Open.
In the ApplicationHost.config file, locate the  tag.
Make sure that all the handlers use valid HTTP methods.
Save the ApplicationHost.config file.

**Cause 2 :**

This problem occurs because a client makes an HTTP request by sending the POST method to a page that is configured to be handled by the StaticFile handler. For example, a client sends the POST method to a static HTML page. However, pages that are configured for the StaticFile handler do not support the POST method.

**Resolution :**

Send the POST request to a page that is configured to be handled by a handler other than the StaticFile handler (for example, the ASPClassic handler). Or, change the request that is being handled by the StaticFile handler so that it is a GET request instead of a POST request.

[Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942051)

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I found there was no such path as stated in Resolution 1, and as I have since discovered (see edit) the error is a consequence of the .aspx (and possibly some other things) being missing, so is probably a red herring.